# Store django forms.MultipleChoiceField in Models directly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Say I have choices defined as follows:

```
choices = (('1','a'),
           ('2','b'),
           ('3','c'))
```

And a form that renders and inputs these values in a MultipleChoiceField,

```
class Form1(forms.Form):
    field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

What is the right way to store `field` in a model.

I can of course loop through the `forms.cleaned_data['field']` and obtain a value that fits in `models.CommaSeperatedIntegerField`.

Again, each time I retrieve these values, I will have to loop and convert into options.

I think there is a better way to do so, as in this way, I am in a way re-implementing the function that CommaSeperateIntegerField is supposed to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first thing I would consider is better normalization of your database schema; if a single instance of your model can have multiple values for this field, the field perhaps should be a linked model with a ForeignKey instead.

If you're using Postgres, you could also use an ARRAY field; Django now has [built-in support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).

If you can't do either of those, then you do basically need to reimplement a (better) version of CommaSeparatedIntegerField. The reason is that CommaSeparatedIntegerField is nothing but [a plain CharField whose default formfield representation is a regex-validated text input](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L436). In other words, it doesn't do anything that's useful to you.

What you need to write is a custom ListField or MultipleValuesField that expects a Python list and returns a Python list, but internally converts that list to/from a comma-separated string for insertion in the database. Read the [documentation on custom model fields](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#howto-custom-model-fields); I think in your case you'll want a subclass of CharField with two methods overridden: [to_python](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#to_python) (convert CSV string to Python list) and [get_db_prep_value](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#get_db_prep_value) (convert Python list to CSV string).

Comment: I think it would be more suitable to subclass the `TextField`, as a `CharField` expects the max_length argument and a PostgreSQL `INT[]` doesn't.

Comment: @danilo Not sure why PostgreSQL INT is relevant here, since the idea is to store comma-separated integers in a non-integer field. In any case, subclassing TextField would be fine too.

Comment: Sorry, I apparently mixed up two different Stackoverflow-questions. My point was - if someone wants to store a list into a Postgres-`INT[]`-field by creating a custom field, he should extend `TextField` :) But looks like that comment doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem and the solution (to me) because as Carl Meyer put it. I don't want a normalized version of this "list of strings" is to just have a CharField in the model. This way your model will store the normalized list of items. In my case this is countries.

So the model declaration is just

```
countries = CharField(max_lenght=XXX)
```

where XXX is a precalculated value of 2x my country list. Because it's simpler for us to apply a check to see if the current country is in this list rather than do it as a M2M to a Country table.

Comment: I should point out that it's not obvious from the official django docs that the MultipleChoiceField will serialize into a proper list of strings.