# Storing an Integer Array in a Django Database

Tags: django, django-models

What is the best way to store an array of integers in a django database?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`CommaSeparatedIntergerField` is no more available since Django 1.9:

[From Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield):

> Deprecated since version 1.9: This field is deprecated in favor of
>   `CharField` with validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list].

---

By default it sets a comma separated integer list field.

> **[int_list_validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#int-list-validator)**
>
> Returns a RegexValidator instance that ensures a string consists of
>   integers separated by sep. It allows negative integers when
>   allow_negative is True.

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import int_list_validator


class YourModel(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    int_list = models.CharField(validators=int_list_validator)   
    ....
```

Comment: It should be something like `models.CharField(validators=[int_list_validator], max_length=100)`

Answer (score 16):

I'm using ArrayField:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield

eg.

```
class Place(models.Model):
    nearby_places_ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), null=True, blank=True)
```

with usage:

```
place.nearby_places_ids = [1,2,3]
place.save()

models.Place.objects.filter(nearby_places_ids__contains=[1])
<QuerySet [<Place: Hostel DIC>]>

models.Place.objects.filter(nearby_places_ids__contains=[1,2,3,4])
<QuerySet []>
```

Comment: SQLite does not support this Field

Answer (score 9):

[CommaSeparatedIntegerField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) comes to mind instantly. It is implemented as `VARCHAR` on most database backends. To be sure though, you may want to skim through `django/db/backends/*`.

Comment: That basically means that I have to convert the string back into integers myself?

Comment: This is super dated information. The current dev (nor the current release: [v1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield)) site that you linked, doesn't mention a CommaSeparatedIntegerField.

Answer (score 6):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399622/store-django-forms-multiplechoicefield-in-models-directly/1400531#1400531) for a description of a possible alternative version of CommaSeparatedIntegerField that would do more of the work for you (converting from list to string and back). Maybe you could check in with that guy about whether he wrote it already :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PostgreSQL, you can store array types natively.

See for example: https://github.com/aino/django-arrayfields and https://github.com/ecometrica/django-dbarray

Answer (score 0):

Use *ArrayField* . Here's the syntax :

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
class SampleModel(models.Model):
     my_integer_array =  ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField(),
         default= [1,1,0,0], blank=False,null = False, size = 4)
```

To store a complete array :

```
SampleModel.my_integer_array = [3,4,5,6]
SampleModel.save()
```

To store/update a single element :

```
SampleModel.my_integer_array[2] =7
SampleModel.save()
```

To fetch the entire array :

```
my_variable = SampleModel.my_integer_array
```

To fetch a single element :

```
e = SampleModel.my_integer_array[3]
```

Note : *ArrayField* can only be used when you are using postgreSQL as the database