# Storing an array of integers with Django

Tags: python, django, arrays, integer

I've been trying to store an array of integers in a field of a Django model. Based on [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429293/storing-an-integer-array-in-a-django-database), I've been trying to do so using a CommaSeparatedIntegerField, however this has proved less intuitive than the name would imply.

If I have a comma-separated list of integers `(list = [12,23,31])`, and I store it in a CommaSeparatedIntegerField, it comes back as a string `(retrieved_list outputs u'[1,2,3]')`. I cannot simply retrieve my integers : for instance, `int(retrieved_list[1])` outputs 1 whereas `list[1]` would output 23.

So, do I have to do the parsing by hand, or is there any other solution? And how exactly does a CommaSeparatedIntegerField differs from a CharField? Seems to me like they behave pretty much the same...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between this field type and a CharField is that it validates that the data is in the proper format - only digits separated by ','. You can view the source for the class at http://docs.nullpobug.com/django/trunk/django.db.models.fields-pysrc.html#CommaSeparatedIntegerField (expand the '+').

You can turn such a string into an actual Python list value (not array - list is the proper term for Python) by using eval.

```
>>> eval("[1,2,3,4]")
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

EDIT: eval has safety concerns, however and a better method is to use literal_eval as suggest by Alvin in another answer.

Comment: Can't believe this didn't even have one upvote.  Here's one! :-)

Comment: you could use `json.loads("[1,2,3,4]")` which also returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 10):

Eval was accepted as answer above -- avoid the temptation it's just not safe

See: [Python: make eval safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513292/python-make-eval-safe)

There is a [literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=literal#ast.literal_eval) function that could be used the same way:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("[1,2,3,4]")
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```